# Screen is cropped regardless of the PS4 screen calibration

Tags: ps4, cities-skylines

Regardless of how I set the PS4 screen position in the main ps4 settings the Cities screen is cropping out the edges, so I can't read all the messages that appear.

You can see the screenshot below how part of the message is cropped out, and it's the same for messages in the top-left too.

There doesn't seem to be any settings in-game to manage screen size / position. Am I missing some other solution here?

It's running on a 720p tv through HDMI,if that makes any difference.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your TV is overscanning the image. A lot of cheap TVs do that and hopefully there's an option to turn it off in the menu settings, but it is very likely that there is nothing you can do about it.

Comment: tl;dr it's a TV issue, not a game/console issue.

Comment: Yeah, I guess you might be right. I didn't think that TVs have done that since the old CRT days, but apparently I was wrong.
Oh well. One more excuse to add to the list for why I need to upgrade to a 4k!

Comment: I'm fairly certain even 4K TV's do that, but most TVs have the option to turn overscan off one way or another. I believe it's only the cheapest TVs that don't have that option (don't quote me on that :P)

Comment: Mine isn't a cheap one (an LG something or other), but it is relatively old. While I don't believe there's a direct setting for overscanning, there are different display options and ratio's I can choose from.